# Choose/Discover signature for extern function call at compile-time

Tags: c, linker, extern

I call a function in an external library that added a parameter between version 1 and version 2. I want to support both versions.

At this point I do

```
 extern void run(int param1); 

 ... in the code ...
 run(123);
```

In version 2 it's run(int param1, int param2).

Can I detect the version of the library I link against somehow dynamically? (number of parameters)

I'd like to avoid having to let the user set the library version in the Makefile and solve this with preprocessor-ifs.

Comment: What library is it?  If the developer of the library was forward thinking, then there would be a way for library user to get the library version.  Could be a function or global var.  Without such version readability, changing call signature of a library API is just evil.

Comment: That's not available unfortunately; Though I guess I could grab/grep it from the README in the library directory when I run make.

Answer (score 0):

The way C code works is that the v1 function would only have access to the first passed parameter.  As long as that parameter has the same meaning to both versions, you can safely pass both parameters to whichever function is provided.  v1 will only see the first; v2 will see both parameters.

This power comes from the C's architectural need to support a variable number of arguments, such as `printf()`.  The calling code removes parameters after the call completes, and the parameters are pushed right-to-left so that the first (left-most) parameter is always at top of the stack frame.

Only if the library's API was horribly desecrated for the upgrade would the first parameter have a different meaning.

Comment: Assuming that this function is declared in the header, the compiler won't accept this code. Even if it does (or it isn't declared), nothing in the standard guarantee that it will work. (Compiler may implement different calling-conversion for variardic functions)